# accessing member function after deleting object ? weird behaviour explanation required

Tags: c++, destructor, undefined-behavior

I am not able to understand following behaviour in c++.I am using gcc 4.4.1

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class call{
        private:
        int *ptr;

    public :
    call()
    {
    cout<<"\nConstructor called\n";
    }

    void allocate()
    {
            ptr=new int[10];
    }

    void test()
    {
            cout<<"\nTesting\n";
    }

    ~call()
     {
            if(ptr)
            {

             cout<<"\nptr deleted\n";
             delete [] ptr;
                     ptr=NULL;
            }
      }
};





int main()
{
    call *p=new call();
    p->allocate();
    p->test();

    delete p;

    p->test();
    p->test();

    p->allocate();

    p->test();
    p->test();

return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
Constructor called

Testing

ptr deleted

Testing

Testing

Testing

Testing
```

In the above code , even after deleting object (delete p) , I am still able to access member function(void test()) of the class. How c++ is allowing me to access member function of the class if that object is deleted.

Comment: There's good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: Duplicate hundreds of times over.

Comment: @CarlNorum I'm always wondering what leads people to try things that are wrong and then ask for a reasonable explanation...

Comment: It's not a null instance in this case, but that's also good information, and a freed pointer is analogous to a null pointer in that you certainly shouldn't be operating on them.

Comment: will it fine if i call in following sequence in main() p->allocate(); p->test(); p->~call(); p->~call(); p->~call(); delete p;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's *no reasonable explanation.*

Your code invokes **undefined behavior,** and this means that it's not required to do anything particular. It can crash, but it doesn't need to do so. It can pretend to be "working fine", as in your case.

Maybe the memory manager on your OS didn't yet recycle the freed/deleted memory, that's all. But **you should really not rely on this behavior.**

Comment: will it fine if i call in following sequence in main()

   `p->allocate();`
`p->test();`
`p->~call();`
`p->~call();`
`p->~call();`
`delete p;`

Answer (score 1):

because after you did the following

```
delete p;
```

you didn't set p to NULL

try the following

```
void test()
{
    cout<<"Testing "<< ptr[0] << "\n";
}

void allocate()
{
     ptr=new int[10];
     ptr[0] = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a pointer after it's been freed causes *undefined behaviour*.  That means *anything* can happen, including the appearance of "correct behaviour".